# How can I view the content of a backup of the dconf database file?

Tags: dconf

I've taken a backup of the file where my [`dconf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf) database is stored (`~/.config/dconf/user` which is a binary file), and now I need to move some keys from the backup to the `dconf` in use.

How can I view the content of the backed up `dconf` without putting it "in place" and view it with for example `dconf-editor`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To view the content of that file you could rename it - e.g. `test` - place it under `~/.config/dconf/` and then have `dconf` read/dump the settings from that file.
[By default](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html), `dconf` reads the *user-db* found in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf/`:

> A `"user-db"` line specifies a user database.
>   These databases are found in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf/`. The name of the file to open in that
>   directory is exactly as it is written in the profile. This file is
>   expected to be in the binary dconf database format. Note that
>   `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` cannot be set/modified per terminal or session,
>   because then the writer and reader would be working on different DBs
>   (the writer is started by DBus and cannot see that variable).

As a result, you would need a custom profile that points to that particular db file  - e.g. `user-db:test` and then instruct `dconf` to dump the data (using the custom profile) via the `DCONF_PROFILE` environment variable:

```
cd
cp /path_to_backup_dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/test
printf %s\\n "user-db:test" > db_profile
DCONF_PROFILE=~/db_profile dconf dump / > old_settings
```

The result is a file (`old_settings`) containing the settings from your backed up `dconf` file, e.g.:

```
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
font-name='DejaVu Sans Oblique 10'
document-font-name='DejaVu Sans Oblique 10'
gtk-im-module='gtk-im-context-simple'
clock-show-seconds=true
icon-theme='HighContrast'
monospace-font-name='DejaVu Sans Mono Oblique 10'

[org/gnome/desktop/input-sources]
sources=@a(ss) []
xkb-options=@as []

[org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences]
num-workspaces=4
titlebar-font='DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique 10'

.......
```

You could then remove those files:

```
rm -f ~/db_profile ~/.config/dconf/test
```

and load the old settings into the current database:

```
dconf load / < old_settings
```

---

If you want to dump only specific settings just provide the path:

```
DCONF_PROFILE=~/db_profile dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/
[/]
num-workspaces=4
titlebar-font='DejaVu Sans Bold Oblique 10'
```

but note that for each path you should have a different file and when you load it you should specify the path accordingly:

```
dconf load /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/ < old_wm_settings
```

---

Also note that, due to upstream changes, older `dconf` databases might contain paths, keys and values that are invalid in newer versions so full compatibility between db-files created by different versions of `dconf` isn't always guaranteed. In that case, you would have to inspect the resulting `old_settings` file and manually remove or edit the entries that are invalid before loading it into your current database.

Comment: I think *reading* is not a problem. Just set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to another directory. No profile magic needed. But writing to an arbitrary dconf file is hard and may make your profile trick necessary.

Comment: I can confirm the profile changes aren't for reading/dumping needed.

Comment: @TorstenBronger yupp, you're right, this works easily in a terminal: `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/some/backup/path/home/user/.config dconf-editor`

Comment: Why the heck are users supposed do this snapfu just to view the content? The "Dconf Editor" tool should have come with the ability to open a database file, or the dconf dump should have had the ability to take an input file path.

Answer (score -4):

I think the first answer overly-complicated the matter, so let's try again, using `/org/cinnamon/` as an example namespace to backup and restore:

**To backup /org/cinnamon/:**

From a terminal, run:

`dconf dump /org/cinnamon/ > backup_of_my_cinnamon_settings`

save the `backup_of_my_cinnamon_settings` file somewhere for later

**To reset /org/cinnamon/ to defaults:**

`dconf reset -f /org/cinnamon/`

Note, cinnamon may freeze or crash doing this

**To restore all your settings for /org/cinnamon:**

`dconf load /org/cinnamon/ < backup_of_my_cinnamon_settings`

---

The process would be the same for `/org/gnome/terminal/`, etc.

For best results, update app references when they are not running.

Thanks to [Cinnamon docs](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/wiki/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-cinnamon-settings-(dconf)) for the tips.

Comment: I think you should try again: the question here is _not_ how to backup and restore some settings but how to _view_ (and maybe _load_) the settings from a saved _binary_ file.